# "expect" match "send" string, why?

Tags: shell, terminal, tcl, expect

I found that **expect** command just after **send** command match data from **send** command.

Let see, *my.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
read line
echo ok
```

*my.exp* (some code is redundant, I emulate DejaGNU testing framework...):

```
set passn 0
proc pass {msg} { global passn; incr passn; send_user "PASS: $msg\n" }
set failn 0
proc fail {msg} { global failn; incr failn; send_user "FAIL: $msg\n" }
proc check {} {
    global passn failn;
    send_user "TOTOAL: [expr $passn + $failn], PASSED: $passn, FAIL: $failn\n"
    if {$failn == 0} { exit 0 } { exit 1 }
}

set timeout 1

spawn ./my.sh

send hello\n
expect {
    -ex hello {
        send_user "~$expect_out(0,string)~\n"
        pass hello
    }
    default { fail hello }
}
expect {
    -ex ok { pass ok }
    default { fail ok }
}

check
```

When run *expect my.exp* I get:

```
spawn ./my.sh
hello
~hello~
PASS: hello
ok
PASS: ok
TOTOAL: 2, PASSED: 2, FAIL: 0
```

I don't understand why *hello* matched!! Please tell me. I already reread:

- http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expect` works with
[pseudoterminal devices](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty). They are
much like normal terminals: unless you disable echo (using expect's
`stty` command), whatever you send is also visible as your "terminal
output" (which is expect's input).

`stty_init` variable is used by expect to set up newly created
pseudoterminals. If you add `set stty_init -echo` to the beginnig of
`my.exp`, the test will begin to fail.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't hope that question about **Expect** can be answered in SO! One think that I don't understand why my code fail with **stty -echo**, which I try when debug issue, but with **stty_init -echo** work... Just a minute I going to read **man expect**...

Comment: Also with **set stty_init {-echo raw}** I fix issue with **\r**. I use **Expect** to test my line oriented protocol and it is annoying instead of **\n** use **\r\n** in match patterns...